# JS/Jquery and firebase login page issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, loops, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build a login page. After a user has logged in correctly I want to exit the index.html page and redirect to my portfolio.html page.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
 if(user) {
 window.location = 'portfolio.html'; 
} else {
 // No user is signed in.
 // window.location = 'index.html';
 console.log("Not logged in");

  }
});
```

The code above does switch pages, but then constantly reloads the page over and over again in a loop. I am very stuck friends:(.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: THe reason for this can be that when the page reloads , you are not logged in again. Are you enabling Auth state persistence ? Please have a look here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it like, you got redirected to portfolio.html, the auth code is exectuted, the user object is already there, so it redirects you to portfolio again. Try adding

```
if(window.location.indexOf("portfolio.html") === -1){
//redirection here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that the piece of code is also executed in your portfolio.html. So when the page is loaded, firebase checks if there is a user logged in from web storage and in your case, the user is logged in previously. So the listener will be triggered again and reload the page.